# What is going on with this Data Explorer graph?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I just found a link to [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/200561).

Running the query (which takes some time) and viewing the graph produces some...odd...results

[image]

So what is it the query does, and is the results it produces "expected?"